# Is there anything wrong with using Advisory Locks this way (bitwise-or on most significant bits)

Tags: postgresql

From what I've seen, the pg advisory lock functions take either 1 bigint or 2 ints (so the same thing really). In the `pg_locks` table, no matter which one you use, it populates the `classid` and `objid` columns (32bit each).

Now, if I want to lock something using a bigint index and not have conflicts with other bigint locks from operations in other parts of my software, then, I was thinking of doing this:

```sql
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock($1 | x'0100000000000000'::bigint);
```

Using the most significant 8 bits in the 64bit bigint, as a sort of "namespace". Sure I can see the risk if my index somehow exceeds `2^(63-8)` it would become "a problem".

Other than that, is there anything fundamentally wrong in (ab)using the Postgres advisory lock bigint "key" this way? Is there something that will explode back in my face?

Comment: Why would you want so many locked "resources" at the same time? Even if a lock costs only 1 byte, 2^63 locks would consume almost exabyte.

Comment: @fukanchik I don't want 2^63 locks. I want to use a bigint index as the lock key without having overlap from another table's index. Meaning lock(Table_A.index) must not conflict with lock(Table_B.index). So, I just "reserve" the most significat bits for some bitwise or 0x00... to 0xFF..., where ... will just be part of the table index.

Comment: Then use table's `Oid` as a "namespace": `SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock( (select 'table_A'::regclass::oid)::int,  x'100'::int);`

Comment: Table's `Oid` is 32 bit, I have have indices that will go over 32 bit and overflow into the `Oid` (edit: or get trimmed [I assume] if I go with the lock(int, int) function signature which is also no good to me). That's why I decided on 8 bits, as that leaves the other bits for the index and gives me plenty of pseudo-namespaces for my locks.

Comment: Are you trying to implement row-level locking?

Comment: No. Row level locking would not work for this case, as I need to lock existing rows and any rows from being inserted into a table X, where the locking condition/key is a FK to table Y. I don't want to lock the specific row in table Y either. I am certain this is a good place to use advisory locks, if the index happened to be 32 bit, there would be no question and I would be doing table namespace + index. So, the only question I have, is still "Is there something fundamentally wrong with that lock + bitwise or in PG?".